# Rails 3 nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, nested

I'm trying to understand how to nest models with rails (active records to then apply it to my project with mongodb)

I'm following this railscast tutorial:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

but i'm stuck at the beginning when I can't display the form to add new questions to the survey.

I have set up the relationships in the models

models/survey.erb:

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
  validates_presence_of :name
end
```

models/question.erb:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
  validates_presence_of :content
end
```

controllers/surveys_controller.rb:

```
def new
  @survey = Survey.new
  @survey.questions.build

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @survey }
  end
end
```

views/survey/_form.html.erb"

```
<%= form_for(@survey) do |f| %>
  <% if @survey.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@survey.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this survey from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @survey.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <h3>Add new question</h3>
  <% f.fields_for :questions do |p| %>
    <%= p.label :content, "Questions" %><br />
    <%= p.text_area :content, :rows => 3 %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

but when I try to build the nested form, it doesn't work. I don't get any errors but the form doesn't show.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a `<%=`, not a `<%` on your `field_for` line, similar to your `form_for` line. Otherwise, the actual nested form won't get displayed.

```
<%= f.fields_for :questions do |p| %>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I got confused with something that I read recently. Control logic don't need <%= in rails if it doesn't output code. So I thought that the field_for was a control thingy to output the inner code :(

Answer (score 1):

You are not taking full advantage of the nested forms in your example.

To DRY things up you should replace the `form_for(@survey)`  by  `nested_form_for(@survey)`

and then you can pull out the questions sub-form into it's own partial, and just do a:

```
f.fields_for :questions   # without a block
```

and handle the questions form under ./app/views/questions/_form.html.erb as a regular `form_for(@question)`

This way you don't have to duplicate code for the questions form inside your survey form.

P.S.: You will need to add "nested_form" Gem to your Gemfile.

Comment: but that's a gem or is part of rails?

Comment: It's a Gem, called "nested_from" -- you'll need to add it to your Gemfile

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else get's stuck on this and winds up here, like me, this issue is the missing '=' in the fields_for call's brackets: '<%= f.fields_for...'